# Mongoose Date.now time is not accurate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

I've been tearing my hair out for the past 2 hours, At first I thought Moment.js is the culprit for not returning a correct time, but it was mongoose Date.now that has been doing some evil stuff.

Here's the code

```
const moment = require('moment');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const item = new mongoose.Schema({
   time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   time2: { type: Date }
});
```

As you can see I have two fields, one is for the default date from mongoose and the other one is just a field for storing date.

```
item.pre('save', function() {
   console.log(moment()); // Showing a correct date and time
   console.log(this.time); // Showing a correct date but false time
   this.time2 = moment(); // When it is saved to the database, it will show a correct date but false time

});
```

The result is

```
moment("2017-01-09T19:42:48.896") // the first console.log. This is correct, the time is correct
2017-01-09T11:42:48.884Z // Second console.log. The date is correct but the time is FALSE
```

I thought If I do this everything will be solved

```
const item = new mongoose.Schema({
       time: { type: Date, default: moment() },
       time2: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
 });
```

But you know what is the console.log for the first field which is `time`?

```
2017-01-09T11:42:48.884Z // it is this time which is WRONG TIME
```

My guess would be that mongoose data type which is Date has an inaccurate timezone check.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: looks like your mongodb is storing in UTC format, can you tell me how many hours your timezone is ahead of utc, what is your timezone??

Comment: You are comparing two different things. moment() gives  time in your local time zone and Date.now is time in UTC( universal time) . The only reason mongoose has that way is because mongodb saves it that way. There is nothing to fix here. Just convert your fetched mongoose date back to local time zone using moment library. Pleas read a little bit about time zone and it will all makes sense.

Comment: @SagarRedd can you put an answer here so I could accept it?

Comment: @sinusGob Added comment as an answer. Let me know if you're looking for anything in specific.

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing two different things. `moment()` gives time in local time zone and `Date.now` is time in UTC. The only reason mongoose has that way is because mongo db saves it that way. No fix is required here.

Just convert the fetched mongoose date back to local time zone using moment library.